# Bootstrap-slider loading not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-slider

I think I am having an issue with being able to select DOM elements that are part of [bootstrap-slider](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider).  When I attempt to target them with events such as `click`, nothing gets fired.

When I refresh the page, all events fire properly.  Why might this occur?

```
$(document).on("page:change", function() {
    $(".slider-handle")
        .on("mousedown", function() {
            console.log("FOCUSED")
            $(".active-handle").removeClass("active-handle");
            $(this).addClass("active-handle");
        })
        .on("mouseup", function() {
            console.log("REMOVED")
            $(this).removeClass("active-handle");
            $(".active-handle").removeClass("active-handle");
        })
        .on("click", function() {
            console.log("REMOVED")
            $(this).removeClass("active-handle");
            $(".active-handle").removeClass("active-handle");
        })
```

Comment: did you notice any error in console

Comment: Try jquery event delegate()

Comment: No errors in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If elements aren't visible at load jQuery can't assign event handlers. Try this:

```
$(document).on("mousedown", ".slider-handle", function() {
```

To improve performance, replace `document` with any persistent ancestor element.

Comment: This works for `mouseup` and `click` but `mousedown` still doesn't fire.

Comment: @Jeremy Thomas the approach will work on mouse down,see my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bapo2ah5/2/